# WebExceptionHandler : How to write a body with Spring Webflux

Tags: spring, exception, spring-webflux

I want to handle the Exception of my api by adding a WebExceptionHandler.
I can change the status code, but I am stuck when i want to change the body of the response : ex adding the exception message or a custom object.

Does anyone have exemple ?

How I add my WebExceptionHandler :

```
HttpHandler httpHandler = WebHttpHandlerBuilder.webHandler(toHttpHandler(routerFunction))
  .prependExceptionHandler((serverWebExchange, exception) -> {

      exchange.getResponse().setStatusCode(myStatusGivenTheException);
      exchange.getResponse().writeAndFlushWith(??)
      return Mono.empty();

  }).build();
```

Answer (score 30, accepted):

`WebExceptionHandler` is rather low level, so you have to directly deal with the request/response exchange.

Note that:

- the `Mono<Void>` return type should signal the end of the response handling; this is why it should be connected to the `Publisher` writing the response
- at this level, you're dealing directly with data buffers (no serialization support available)

Your `WebExceptionHandler` could look like this:

```
(serverWebExchange, exception) -> {

  exchange.getResponse().setStatusCode(myStatusGivenTheException);
  byte[] bytes = "Some text".getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
  DataBuffer buffer = exchange.getResponse().bufferFactory().wrap(bytes);
  return exchange.getResponse().writeWith(Flux.just(buffer));
}
```

Comment: When I try this example the IDE highlights that Flux.just(buffer) is an incompatible type with the writeAndFlushWith param. This is expecting: Mono<Void> writeAndFlushWith(Publisher<? extends Publisher<? extends DataBuffer>> body);    Has this signature changed?

Comment: Fixed a typo in my answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

Given the answer, to serialize object I use this way :

```
 Mono<DataBuffer> db = commonsException.getErrorsResponse().map(errorsResponse -> {

     ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
     try {
         return objectMapper.writeValueAsBytes(errorsResponse);
     } catch (JsonProcessingException e) {
          return e.getMessage().getBytes();
     }
}).map(s -> exchange.getResponse().bufferFactory().wrap(s));

exchange.getResponse().getHeaders().add("Content-Type", "application/json");
exchange.getResponse().setStatusCode(commonsException.getHttpStatus());
return exchange.getResponse().writeWith(db);
```

Answer (score 5):

`ServerResponse` has a method `writeTo` which can be used to write your body to `ServerExchange` (Spring framework does it this way). Only problem is that you have to provide `Context`as a second parameter, so I have just copied `HandlerStrategiesResponseContext` from framework implementation.

Make sure that you are using at least Spring Boot 2.0.0 M2, before this version `WebExceptionHandler` was not registered while using `RouterFunctions`.

```
import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus
import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus.*
import org.springframework.http.codec.HttpMessageWriter
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component
import org.springframework.web.reactive.function.server.HandlerStrategies
import org.springframework.web.reactive.function.server.ServerResponse
import org.springframework.web.reactive.result.view.ViewResolver
import org.springframework.web.server.ServerWebExchange
import org.springframework.web.server.WebExceptionHandler


@Component
class GlobalErrorHandler() : WebExceptionHandler {

    override fun handle(exchange: ServerWebExchange, ex: Throwable): Mono<Void> =
        handle(ex)
                .flatMap {
                    it.writeTo(exchange, HandlerStrategiesResponseContext(HandlerStrategies.withDefaults()))
                }
                .flatMap {
                    Mono.empty<Void>()
                }

    fun handle(throwable: Throwable): Mono<ServerResponse> {

        return when (throwable) {
            is EntityNotFoundException -> {
                createResponse(NOT_FOUND, "NOT_FOUND", "Entity not found, details: ${throwable.message}")
            }
            else -> {
                createResponse(INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR, "GENERIC_ERROR", "Unhandled exception")
            }
        }
    }

    fun createResponse(httpStatus: HttpStatus, code: String, message: String): Mono<ServerResponse> =
        ServerResponse.status(httpStatus).syncBody(ApiError(code, message))
}

private class HandlerStrategiesResponseContext(val strategies: HandlerStrategies) : ServerResponse.Context {

    override fun messageWriters(): List<HttpMessageWriter<*>> {
        return this.strategies.messageWriters()
    }

    override fun viewResolvers(): List<ViewResolver> {
        return this.strategies.viewResolvers()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

for anyone looking at a way to write *JSON* response body, here's a Kotlin code sample:

```kotlin
fun writeBodyJson(body: Any, exchange: ServerWebExchange) =
    exchange.response.writeWith(
        Jackson2JsonEncoder().encode(
            Mono.just(body),
            exchange.response.bufferFactory(),
            ResolvableType.forInstance(body),
            MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8,
            Hints.from(Hints.LOG_PREFIX_HINT, exchange.logPrefix)
        )
    )
```

not 100% sure that's the way to go though, would like to get some opinions.

Answer (score 0):

I needed to render a view and couldn't find a way to do this via the exception handler (only found examples using controllers which would require a needless redirect) so I used the `ServerResponseResultHandler` to render it from the handler. This gives the required `Mono<Void>` response.

```
/** Used when creating the {@link HandlerResult}
 *  Taken from https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/5.3.x/spring-webflux/src/main/java/org/springframework/web/reactive/function/server/support/HandlerFunctionAdapter.java
 */
private static final MethodParameter RETURN_TYPE;

static {
    try {
        Method method = ServerAccessDeniedHandler.class.getMethod("handle", ServerWebExchange.class, AccessDeniedException.class);
        RETURN_TYPE = new MethodParameter(method, -1);
    }
    catch (NoSuchMethodException ex) {
        throw new IllegalStateException(ex);
    }
}

@Autowired
private ServerResponseResultHandler responseHandler;

public class CustomAccessDeniedHandler implements ServerAccessDeniedHandler {
    @Override
    public Mono<Void> handle(ServerWebExchange exchange, AccessDeniedException ex) {
        return ReactiveSecurityContextHolder.getContext()
            .map(SecurityContext::getAuthentication)
            .filter(auth -> auth != null && auth.isAuthenticated())
            .switchIfEmpty(Mono.empty())
            .flatMap(auth -> ServerResponse
                .status(HttpStatus.FORBIDDEN)
                // Give name of view and model attributes it requires
                .render("unauthorized", Map.of("varName", varValue))
                .flatMap(response -> responseHandler.handleResult(exchange,
                    new HandlerResult(this, response, RETURN_TYPE)))
            );
    }
}
```