# Spring Cloud gateway send response in filter

Tags: spring-boot, spring-cloud-gateway, spring-reactive

I am using spring cloud gateway as edge server. 
This is the flow

If request has a header named 'x-foo' then find the header value, get a string from another server and send that string as response instead of actually proxying the request.

Here is code for Filter DSL

```
@Bean
    public RouteLocator routes(RouteLocatorBuilder builder) {
        return builder.routes()
                .route("foo-filter", r -> r.header('x-foo').and().header("x-intercepted").negate()
                        .filters(f -> f.filter(fooFilter))
                        .uri("http://localhost:8081")) // 8081 is self port, there are other proxy related configurations too
                .build();
    }
```

Code for Foo filter

```
@Component
@Slf4j
public class FooFilter implements GatewayFilter {

    @Autowired
    private ReactiveRedisOperations<String, String> redisOps;

    @Value("${header-name}")
    private String headerName;

    @Override
    public Mono<Void> filter(ServerWebExchange exchange, GatewayFilterChain chain) {
        ServerHttpRequest request = exchange.getRequest();
        var foo = request.getHeaders().getFirst(headerName);

        return redisOps.opsForHash()
                .get("foo:" + foo, "response")
                .doOnSuccess(s -> {
                    log.info("data on success");
                    log.info(s.toString()); // I am getting proper response here
                    if (s != null) {
                        ServerHttpResponse response = exchange.getResponse();
                        response.setStatusCode(HttpStatus.OK);
                        response.getHeaders().set("x-intercepted", "true");

                        byte[] bytes = s.toString().getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8);

                        DataBuffer buffer = response.bufferFactory().wrap(bytes);

                        response.writeWith(Mono.just(buffer));

                        response.setComplete();
                    }
                })
                .then(chain.filter(exchange));
    }

}
```

The problem is, the response has the response is getting proper 200 code, the injected header is present on response but the data is not available in response.

Comment: This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45215416/9279181) seems to be related to your question.

Comment: Exactly what I needed.

Comment: However this is giving me error after return. java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: null
 at org.springframework.http.ReadOnlyHttpHeaders.putAll(ReadOnlyHttpHeaders.java:131) ~[spring-web-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
 Suppressed: reactor.core.publisher.FluxOnAssembly$OnAssemblyException: 
Error has been observed at the following site(s):
 |_ checkpoint ? org.springframework.cloud.gateway.filter.WeightCalculatorWebFilter [DefaultWebFilterChain]
 |_ checkpoint ? org.springframework.security.web.server.authorization.AuthorizationWebFilter [DefaultWebFilterChain]

Comment: Hi @Akshay, Please share the updated code with stacktrace

Comment: Apparently I had used `switchIfEmpty` and it was case early execution.

Answer (score 5):

This is how I got working.

- Use `flatMap` instead of `doOnSuccess`
- don't use `then` or `switchIfEmpty` instead use `onErrorResume`
- Return the `response.writeWith`

```
    @Component
    @Slf4j
    public class FooFilter implements GatewayFilter {
    
        @Autowired
        private ReactiveRedisOperations<String, String> redisOps;
    
        @Value("${header-name}")
        private String headerName;
    
        @Override
        public Mono<Void> filter(ServerWebExchange exchange, GatewayFilterChain chain) {
            ServerHttpRequest request = exchange.getRequest();
            var foo = request.getHeaders().getFirst(headerName);
    
            return redisOps.opsForHash()
                    .get("foo:" + foo, "response")
                    .flatMap(s -> {
                        log.info("data on success");
                        log.info(s.toString()); // I am getting proper response here
                        if (s != null) {
                            ServerHttpResponse response = exchange.getResponse();
                            response.setStatusCode(HttpStatus.OK);
                            response.getHeaders().set("x-intercepted", "true");
    
                            byte[] bytes = s.toString().getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
    
                            DataBuffer buffer = response.bufferFactory().wrap(bytes);
    
                            return response.writeWith(Mono.just(buffer));
   
                        }else{ return chain.filter(exchange).then(Mono.fromRunnable(() -> {log.info("It was empty")} }
                    })
                    .onErrorResume(chain.filter(exchange));
        }
    }
```

Comment: Did this really return the response object?

Comment: Yes, we are using it in Prod